# creating a matrix table with 2 independend links to other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I did search for an similar question but didn't really find what I was looking.

I have for example the following table structures:

(notice that this is an example to give an insight of my problem)

**table: matrix_links**

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| id | name                | table1      | table2      | intersection_table      |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | page autohorisation | pages       | groups      | group_has_pages         |
|  2 | rights              | rights      | groups      | group_has_rights        |
|  3 | Banana              | Banana      | kiwi        | kiwi_has_banana         |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

**table: pages**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | page1       |
|  2 | page2       |
|  3 | page3       |
+----+-------------+
```

**table: groups**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | group1      |
|  2 | group2      |
|  3 | group3      |
+----+-------------+
```

**table: group_has_pages**

```
+----------+-----------+
| page_id  | group_id  |
+----------+-----------+
| 1        | 1         |
+----------+-----------+
```

In my code this will generate:

```
+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| page authorisation      | group1   | group2   | group3   |
+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
|  page1                  | x        | o        | o        |
|  page2                  | o        | o        | o        |
|  page3                  | o        | o        | o        |
+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

This will define the pages the group can access, and will save the checked checkbox in the intersection table.

I don't think this is an good practice; to save table names in the column. I am looking for an solution that is good practice to work with.

Notice that:

- I will reuse the code as much as possible
- I don't change table names, and stick with my coding style guidelines

Answer (score 0):

You are usually not actually storing a matrix as a matrix in any database as most database management systems restrict the number of columns to a number much much smaller then the number of rows. Therefore you could not create many groups going that way.

The usual solution is flattening your matrix. (Also used for saving space on sparse matrices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix)

You will end up with a table like the following:

```
------------------------------------
page    | group   | authorization
------------------------------------
page1   | group1  | 1
page2   | group2  | 0
page3   | group3  | 0
page2   | group1  | 0
page2   | group2  | 0
page2   | group3  | 0
...
```

Comment: isn't it overkill to add the authorization column? Because in my design when you add an row into the intersection your already telling they are authorised for it. But I want to have multiple matrixes, linking to different tables

Comment: Sure, if it's a true|false thing you do not need the third column. For the rest, I am really unsure what you actually want to achieve, maybe you could elaborate a bit more on your actual aim?

Comment: What my code now does is echo the in the vertical columns the "name" column of table1 the same for horizontal but then using table2. Every checkbox that is checked will be saved in the intersection table (defined in column intersection_table).
But I don't think this is good practice to define the table names to generate an matrix table. http://oi61.tinypic.com/316qgk6.jpg

Comment: @Ismail, I guess your gut feeling here is right. Especially for something as basic as authorization I do not see why you would need some flexible architecture like yours with tables names stored for reference in other tables. Probably your concept of pages, groups and rights is a fixed for the duration of the project. So just hardcode the dependencies/relations between them on the db level.